# I'm not sure why I'm getting an index out of range error

Tags: go, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm getting the error:

panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 7 [running]:
main.start(0xc0000540e0, 0x8, 0xc0000542a0, 0x63, 0x1, 0xc00249a0c0)

when I try to run my program on certain logs, but not all of them.

The code that is causing this error seems to be:

```
end, _ := time.Parse("15:04:05", lines[len(lines)-1].Timestamp)
start, _ := time.Parse("15:04:05", lines[0].Timestamp)
midnight, _ := time.Parse("15:04:05", "00:00:00")
duration := end.Sub(start).Seconds()
if start.Hour() > end.Hour() {
   toMidnight := 24*3600 - start.Sub(midnight).Seconds()
   timeDuration = toMidnight + end.Sub(midnight).Seconds()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, never omit errors!

To answer your question: if `lines` is empty (`len(lines) == 0`), then `len(lines)-1` will be `-1` which may trigger your error.

Similarly if `lines` is empty, `lines[0]` is also out of range but the previous line panics so you won't end up here.

I'm guessing if `lines` is empty, the whole code should be skipped (nothing to analyze), so first check that. For example:

```
if len(lines) == 0 {
    return
}

// There are lines, it's safe to index it with 0 and len(lines)-1

...
```